# How to maintain changes to comment-template.php

Tags: comments, updates, comments-template

I have made some custom changes to the file `wp-includes\comment-template.php`. These changes are periodically lost and I assume it's related to updates for WordPress and the file is modified/re-written.

I have changed:

```
$comments_link = get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#comments';
```

To:

```
$comments_link = get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#disqus_thread';
```

Is there a way I can persist these changes so they are not lost? Or perhaps there is a better way to make these changes?

*Edit*

I've tried this code in my themes `functions.php` file.

```
function custom_comments_link($comments_link, $post_id){
    return get_permalink($post_id) . '#disqus_thread';
}
add_filter('get_comments_link', 'custom_comments_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: What is the relevant code in your template file(s)?

Comment: Just looking now.

Comment: I've likely missed something, but what file would you expect to find it in? Is it a standard location?

Comment: It's entirely Theme-dependent. It'll be somewhere in the Loop, though.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything...

Answer (score 0):

There's a filter for that: `get_comments_link`. [Refer to source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L618):

```
return apply_filters( 'get_comments_link', $comments_link, $post_id );
```

In an appropriate place (such as a site functionality Plugin), just add a filter via callback:

```
function wpse123906_filter_comments_link( $comments_link, $post_id ) {
    // Return your custom link
    return get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#disqus_thread';
}
add_filter( 'get_comments_link', 'wpse123906_filter_comments_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I tried this in the themes functions.php file with no luck. Should that have worked?

Comment: Yes, it should have. Can you **edit your question** with more details, including what you tried (both the filter, and the template code that outputs the comments link), and what didn't happen as expected/happened unexpectedly?

Comment: You can see that on the main page, comment links are #disqus_thread, then clicking through to a post it is #respond https://scotthelme.co.uk